# How to avoid re-authorization request for a copied Google Spreadsheet + script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that functions as a template for weekly reports. At this point I copy the undated template sheet using DriveApp to a file that has a date in its name. The user is shown the date-specific spreadsheet and can interact with it. When done the user instigates a function that copies of portion of the spreadsheet data to a third file.

Every time the user calls the function an authorization request is shown. I am trying to avoid that authorization request. Is this possible?

I am using a stand-alone Google Apps Script to copy the original template to the date-specific file. I have considered trying to perform all of the UI there. However there are too many contingencies to make that practical. As it stands now once the template is copied then the stand-alone script returns the URL of the date-specific file and ends.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time the user calls the function an authorization request is shown. I am trying to avoid that authorization request. Is this possible?

Publishing your script as an add-on would facilitate this; each user would need to authorize the add-on once, and that authorization would remain in effect in any sheet the add-on was used in.

Comment: is this possible for container bound script too?