# Copy template in Google Sheets and automatically authorize script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have seen similar questions asked, but none of them had A) an answer that I can use or B) the same objective. Here goes:

I have a template of a Google Sheet (call it "Processing") with a script bound to it. When another script runs (copyTemplate.gs), it creates a new copy of Processing based on a unique ID number. The bound script is also copied, which is great.

But I have to manually authorize the Processing script to run. Is there a way to **pre**-authorize so that I don't have to authorize EVERY copy of the Processing spreadsheet? I want this to be user friendly for those less tech savvy. Having to authorize it every single time is tedious and no doubt someone will manage to mess it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid re-authorization request for a copied Google Spreadsheet + script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657242/how-to-avoid-re-authorization-request-for-a-copied-google-spreadsheet-script)

Answer (score 1):

Every script runs as a separate application under the user's account. this is why each needs authorising. if you publish your script as an add-on and then authorise that add-on at domain level (assuming Google Apps for Work) then this is a way to circumvent the requirement.)

Comment: Thanks. I was reading about publishing, but I couldn't figure out if it fit my needs. Since this is for internal business processing, I can keep it as a private web app right?