# Turn OFF "Authorization is required" for Google Sheets Script for own team

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

My English is far from perfect but I will try to explain it as good as possible.
We are a small company which just switched from paper to tablets (Surface GO Win10 Home) and we have one particular sheet which is used for every order (about 100 orders per month). This Google Sheet acts as a template for every single order and includes some easy code which is written in a bound Apps Script project, to handle things like switching the status from started to finished, copying some cells etc.

My problem is, when someone of the team wants to use the created "buttons" in the sheet to activate the script, it asks for authorization for the script the change the sheet. If you enable it, everything works fine but then for every new order you have to enable it again, and again, and it gets really annoying for every team member.

I tried somehow to

- turn it off in the security options as administrator
- tried it in the GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM under API's and services
- tried to make the code somehow public in the script editor options

...but nothing seems not to work. I used VBA programs a lot in Excel VBA but it was more a hobby and I'm not a computer scientist, otherwise it would maybe be easier to solve this problem.

Is there an easy way so every one of my team can work with the sheets created out of a template without any request from Google for authorization every time.

Kind regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy template in Google Sheets and automatically authorize script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249482/copy-template-in-google-sheets-and-automatically-authorize-script)

Comment: New container sheet means new script project thus you **must** provide authorization for it. You (or some other team member) can change the code in these new projects independently of the source project. The solution is to avoid creating a new script project, which means you must use an add-on. An add-on is *one* script project and thus needs to be authorized just *once* (at least, until you change the scopes).

Comment: I tried it now for 3 hours to figure out how to create an add-on but I don't get it.
I installed the G Suite Marketplace SDK and tried to fill everything out but everytime something is missing or not working. If found some kind of description on google but it didn't work out. :(