# Is there an option to permanently approve a script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I programmed a workflow process via Google Forms, Sheets and Docs. A workflow is started via Forms and then replaced in a Docs template via .replaceText placeholders. A copy of the Docs document will be made first.

And there is the problem: Since the approvals take place within the Docs document, the authorization for the script must take place again for each new file. Without it e.g. no eMails are sent.

Is there a way to e.g. copy the permissions of the original template file or to do this in a different way?

Since in our company addons such as Forms Publisher are not desired, I had to do it myself via GAS.

I am still a newbie :)

Comment: No, you can't automatically approve a new script project. Change your workflow so that new script projects are not created, and then you don't have to approve them, e.g. write add-ons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy template in Google Sheets and automatically authorize script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249482/copy-template-in-google-sheets-and-automatically-authorize-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each script that is bound to a new file - whether it is bound to a Sheet, Doc, Form or Slide, the script counts as a new Project and listed separately under 'My Projects' at the [G-Suite Developer Hub](https://script.google.com/home). As a result, you will always have to authorise the running of the script when it's in a new Document.