# How to easily publish add-on to avoid re-authorization request for a copied Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have created a Google Sheet that uses some very simple lines of script (made with Tools --> Script editor inside the Sheet). The script only adds simple functionalities, e.g. to click some buttons or extract the Sheet's filename. Now, the workflow in my company is to make a copy of the main Sheet, and work in the copied version. However, when I call the script in the copied version (e.g. by clicking a button) each time an authorization request is shown. I want to avoid this request. Only 1 user needs the funcionality.

I know that this problem can be solved by publishing my script as an add-on (see [How to avoid re-authorization request for a copied Google Spreadsheet + script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657242/how-to-avoid-re-authorization-request-for-a-copied-google-spreadsheet-script)). When publishing the script I am prompted to create a "User-managed Cloud Platform project". Tried this, but I have zero experience with cloud platform projects, OAuth, JavaScript or whatsoever.

Is there any tutorial or simple explanation available for publishing an add-on to solve this (relatively simple) problem? Or should I not even try without any experience?
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Asking for external resources is off-topic on this site, anyway, please read https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/

Answer (score 1):

To create a Cloud project you just have to go to https://console.developers.google.com -> click create project -> Fill the project info and click in create button [1]. The add-on can help you with your simple problem if you install the add-on for the entire domain so the add-on will be automatically installed in the Spreadsheet App without the need of the authorization request. Here you have some documentation on how to publish your add-on [2][3] and install it for domain-wide [4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

[2] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons

[3] https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/add-ons/domain-wide.html

[4] https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482

Comment: Thank you @Andres Duarte. I have followed both tutorials and succeeded to create and install my own add-on. However, when I create a copy of my sheet and call the script in the new document, it tends to use its own script rather than the add-on, for which it requires new permission. When I empty the Script editor in the new document and activate 'Use in this document' of my add-on, it works.
Is there any way to let this automatically happen?

Comment: Great. Read some of the links i put in the answer to install the add-on as domain wide so it gets automatically installed in all files. Read here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135

Comment: When searching for my add-on in the G Suite Marketplace, I cannot find my addon. Should it pop up, also if I set it to private? When I access the add-on via the Chrome Web Store --> Developer dashboard, I am able to see it in the Chrome store. There, it says "Installed". Should this be sufficient? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AndresDuarte, thanks a lot for your guidance - I've succeeded to publish my shared code as an add-on and publish it domain-wide. The only piece that I miss is how do I call this add-on code from the document-bound script? If I import it as a lib, I'm still get asked for authorization on the first launch...