# Google Apps Script - "authorization required" occurring in every Document created from template

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, authorization

I have a Google Document that has a custom UI menu with an option to add a new page to the Doc and populate it with some data. I use this Doc as template for creating numerous other Docs for a single user via webapp.

So my user comes to my webapp, clicks to generate this Document, the document is created from the aforementioned template Doc (containing the bound script to allow the user to add more pages with additional data). The user clicks in the custom menu to create a new page, and before that chunk of code is executed, he gets the 'Authorization Required' screen. I've already prepared him for this so he know how to proceed - no big deal. he goes on to use the Document for his tasks and closes it when he's finished.

He now needs to generate a new Document from the same template and add additional pages just as before. Once again, he gets the 'Authorization Required' screen. Now he's thinking 'I just authorized this... what's gong on?' and is now confused.

Since these Docs are generated on the fly from within the webapp, I have no way to go in and authorize anything but the script in the template before the user gets to it. But is there really no way to authorize that script in the template doc and have it carry over to all the new docs created from it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the code as a bounded project publish it as an add-on. This way the user only will have to authorize the code once.

Related

- [How to avoid re-authorization request for a copied Google Spreadsheet + script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34657242/1595451)